# How to prepend character to Integer

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

We have a field named `returnNo` that returns integer values when queried from the database.

Example of integer returned is `4098`.

We would like to add the character `T` at the beginning of the integer values and then increment the value by 1. The result of appending this character to the integer value and incrementing it by 1 is then inserted into the database.

When I run the code below, it returns only the integer value without the T character and inserts this value to the database.

What am I doing wrong?

```
Dim retNo As Integer = 0
Dim return_No As String = ""
Dim dteReturned As String = ""
Try
    Dim Sqls As String = "select MAX(returnNo) returnNo from Trials"
    Dim Sqlsr As String = "select DateReturned from Trials where ownerId='" & Session("rOwnerID") & "' "
    Dim prevretcmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(Sqls)
    prevretcmd.Connection = con
    Dim rdr As SqlDataReader = prevretcmd.ExecuteReader()
    If rdr.Read() Then
    dteReturned = rdr("DateReturned").ToString()
    testReturnNo.Text = rdr("ReturnNo").ToString()
    retNo = Convert.ToInt32(testReturnNo.Text.Replace("T", "")) + 1
    returnNo.Text = "T" + retNo.ToString().PadLeft(1, "0"c)
    End If
    rdr.Close()
Catch
    retNo = 1
    returnNo.Text = retNo.ToString()
End Try
```

Comment: Where is the code that inserts the value in the database? In this statement: `returnNo.Text = "T" + retNo.ToString().PadLeft(1, "0"c)` it looks like you are updating a TextBox. This is the value you want to insert back in the database?

Comment: Do you Actually need to store the "T" or just display the "T"?  If in the same situation, I would store the "T" in its own prefix field leaving the number as a number then use a readonly property at the data model layer to append them for display

Comment: @ÉtienneLaneville, once the value is incremented and "T" prepended, the value is stored in returnNo.Text and then inserted into the database. I will post the insert code tomorrow as I can't reach it now. It is closed down.

Thanks very much for your assistance.

Comment: @Hursey, I completely agree with you. My suggestion is to do just that  - insert the number and then during display, prepend the "T" but as you know, sometimes, management thinks it knows it all.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: *"We would like to add character T at the beginning of the integer values and then increment the value by 1"*. How does that make sense? You start with an `Integer` but if you want to prepend characters to it then you have convert it to a `String`, in which case there's no number to increment. You would increment the number first then convert the result to a `String`, e.g. `str = $"T{number + 1}"`. What you then do with that `String` is irrelevant. Saving it to a database is the same as for any other `String`.

Comment: I misspoke there. The  point is that I would like to figure out how to append a character to the beginning of an integer.

Comment: Keep the concept of the integer value and some "T" (text) you want to place in front. See my post below for some code example.

Comment: Yikes. Looks like there's an SQL injection issue in there. That's **very bad**.

Comment: Also, what is the data type of the `ReturnNo` column in the database? If it's an integer column, _you will not be able to include the `T`_.

Comment: "of appending this character"  I believe you mean "prepend" since it is to be positioned prior to the integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 100% separate SQL queries here, and you mixing up getting the MAX number vs that of pulling one row.

Break this out into more bite sized steps.

This code should work:

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    Dim retNo As Integer = 0
    Dim return_No As String = ""
    Dim dteReturned As String = ""

    Dim cmdSQL As New _
            SqlCommand("select MAX(returnNo) returnNo from Trials")

    Dim rstMAX As DataTable = MyRstP(cmdSQL)
    retNo = rstMAX.Rows(0)(0)

    cmdSQL.CommandText =
            "select DateReturned from Trials where ownerId=@ownerid"
    cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@ownerid", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Session("rOwnerID")

    Dim rstTrial As DataRow = MyRstP(cmdSQL).Rows(0)
    dteReturned = rstTrial("DateReturned").ToString()
    testReturnNo.Text = retNo.ToString()
    retNo += 1
    returnNo.Text = "T" & retNo.ToString().PadLeft(6, "0")

End Sub

Public Function MyRstP(cmdSQL As SqlCommand) As DataTable

    Dim rstData As New DataTable
    Using conn As New SqlConnection(My.Settings.TEST4)
        Using (cmdSQL)
            cmdSQL.Connection = conn
            conn.Open()
            rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader)
        End Using
    End Using

    Return rstData

End Function
```

So, our first query gets the max value from the table.

Then our 2nd query gets the database row (date column) based on id value in session().

We get retNo, display it in a text box.

The we add + 1, and then display in the 2nd text box, padded out to 6 "0"s.

The result looks like this:

[image]

So, the max value found in the table was 4098, and we added + 1, and then placed the result with padding of "0"s into that 2nd text box.

## Edit: Data saved is not a integer, but padded string

Ok, so the Max() query going to return a string, one padding with a letter, some "0"'s and then the number.

So, we have to modify our code like this:

```
    Dim rstMAX As DataTable = MyRstP(cmdSQL)
    Dim retNoText As String = ""
    retNoText = rstMAX.Rows(0)(0)
    retNo = retNoText.Substring(1) ' get all characters AFTER first letter skipped
```

So, we get/grab the max string, T000123, OR K000234 or whatever.

We then igonre the FIRST letter, and then add + 1

This means that you might have this

```
  A000123
  B000123
```

Well, then in a sense we have duplicate numbers, since our max query will return the B000123, stirp off the letter B, and then produce a number of 124.

We then format with a T in front.

```
 T000124
```

Note 100% sure if this is what you want, but the above small change will work this way.

Comment: Albert, as usual, thanks so, so much for coming to my rescue again.

It is exactly what I am looking for. There is just one bug I have been trying to resolve for that past several minutes.

The error says, "Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'R000112' to data type int" and it is on this line:

~ returnNo.Text = "T" & retNo.ToString().PadLeft(6, "0")~

I am still trying to figure it out but thought I will just let you know.

Thanks again so much sir for your assistance.

Comment: I assume that retNo is a variable, and is of type int. But, this suggets that you storing the R value in the table. You should ONLY store the number, and in your markup and formatting place the letter "R" in front. And I thought the code was supposed to use T, and not R. So, yes, we need to edit this code somewhat, since the stored value is NOT just a max number, but is a text string stored in the database with a leading letter, then padded with zeros, and then the number. So, we can't just get some max value like R000112 and add +1 to that, can we?  So, we will need a edit here.

Comment: Using a 100% separate table with ONE row of data, and the last number we used would be a better approach here, then we can do a +1, save to that increment table, and then format with the letter R or T or whatever we want in front. Anyway, I'll edit the post to work based on the assumption that we NOT storing a integer value, but some text string in the database with say R or T, and padded with "0"'s in front.  So, in theory, you might JUST want to store the number, and format for display with the T in front. but now with your comments showing a "R", then your question not even consistent.

Comment: My apologies, Albert. I get worked up with excitement sometimes, I miss-type stuff. It is a T. I had to go back to see where I inadvertently used a T.

The issue you raised about not storing the T in the table was also raised earlier by one of the contributors looking at the code.

I have argued several times, unsuccessfully, with management that it makes no sense to store T000112 for instance when you could just store 112 and the reference the T when when displaying records. What I am trying to do now is to prove that it is doable but it doesn't make it a good idea.

Comment: ok then that's ok, see my edit - it will now work assuming the returned max value is to be assumed a "string" with a letter and possible padded zero's in front.

Comment: AWESOME!!!!

I can live with this solution.

Just one last (ignorant) question, what does this row do

retNoText = rstMAX.Rows(0)(0)?

Comment: Well, a table of rows is returned, so it means get the first row (zero based), and then we get the first column (again zero based). So, rows(5)(2) would mean to get the 6th row, and then get the 3rd column value. You can also of course use a column name as string in place of a number, but we have 1 row, and 1 column, so, I think it reasonable to say get the first row, and get the first column, and we don't care about the name of that column.

Comment: Ok, please bear with me here because this is how I learn but you lost me here.

This is the query, select MAX(returnNo) returnNo from Toilets". It has only one column and it returns the largest value. So, it returns just one row for returnNo column name.

Can I just change that to name like rstMAX.Rows("returnNo")?

This is too advanced for me :)

Comment: It only returns one row, but you still have to specify that row. So then this would work: rstMAX.Rows(0)("returnNo").  So that query still returns data  - but only one row.

Comment: I am still struggling with errors:
Exception Details: System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
It doesn't matter whether I use this:
retNo = rstMAX.Rows(0)("returnNo") OR this:

retNo = rstMAX.Rows(0)(0)

Something simpler to replace this line would be so awesome!

Comment: But note my code change - we now stuffing that value into a string variable, since it is is a string type. It not returning a int value anymore. So, note the extra line of code. We declare a variable called retNoText - that's now a string, and it can hold/get/enjoy the results of our MAX() query, and that query is returning a string value - not a number anymore. So, on the next line we "skip" the first character and wind up shoving the integer value into retNo.

Comment: WOW, I am flabbergasted!!!!

This comes so natural, my goodness!

It now WORKS like a dream. Incredible.

Thank you very, very much.

I will like to think God created us equal but some, like you, have very special gifts.